# How to align a picture and text vertically in css

Tags: html, css

Hi I am creating a website and I am trying to align a picture and some text vertically, but I am not being able to do this and the picture is only taking 100% space of the website, this is the code:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0;
}

div.content {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

div.column1 {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

div.column2 {
  width: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="column1">
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="lobby">
        <img src="img/lobby.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>lorem50gsdgsdsgdgsgdfgdfgdfgdfgfdggsd</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
  </div>
</div>
```

The website is divided into 3 columns and I am putting the content on the middle one.

Shouldn't the display flex align them vertically? Why is it not working? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `align-items:center` on flex parent in order to vertically center its children. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) for more details about `flex-container`, and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for more general info about `flexbox`

You can add `justify-content:center` for horizontal alignment.

Comment: On styled the div column 1 so that it had display:flex and align-items:center but still the image doesnt move, and is taking 100% of the space, you know why?

Comment: In your example, there is nothing in column1, so there are not gonna be any changes, but I assume that is not the real case in your project. But in general, If you want to center anything using flexbox, make sure you set display:flex on the closest parent of the element you want to center. Next thing is to make sure that the parent has some height or width, so the children have some place to go to in order to be able to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `display: flex` to the `content` `div`, add just the property `align-items:center` and your text will be centred vertically:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0;
}

div.content {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

div.column1 {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

div.column2 {
  width: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="column1">
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="lobby">
        <img src="img/lobby.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>lorem50gsdgsdsgdgsgdfgdfgdfgdfgfdggsd</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work, try to think with me ok? In order to you understand what is happening here:
First of all if you have a parent div its children should be one bellow one another

1. Your first step is to set the div to have `flex: 1`, [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) check it out this website to learn more.
2. now set the items to be side by side with `display: flex`
3. set the same container with `justify-content: center` and `align-items:center`
4. and if you wish to align the div to the middle of your page, try this: `margin: 0 auto`
5. Here is where the magic happens: `flex-direction: column`, check the documentation [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)